# Center content in middle of page when inside a div over to one side

Tags: css, html, centering

I have a web page with a fixed 200px column on one side (contains the menu). The right side is variable width. The right side will be populated using AJAX. For the default page (when no menu item has been selected) I'm trying to get the company logo centered horizontally in the *page*, not the div into which it is placed. None of the CSS I've tried so far works as expected, with the logo moving left or right of center as the browser window is resized horizontally. Fearing the loss of my remaining hair I'm looking for suggestions.

### Additional info

The CSS for the two columns (from Dreamweaver) is

```
.sidebar1 {
float: left;
width: 200px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
padding: 10px 0;
width: 80%;
float: left;
}
```

The sidebar1 column contains the menu. The right (main) column is simply `<div class="content"></div>` and will receive the content from the server depending on what has been selected from the menu. This div is of course to the right of center relative to the page but I'd like to place the logo into the div but centered horizontally in the page.

Comment: if the logo is in the #content div, you won't be able to do this without some sort or javascript.

Comment: I agree with @jlbruno - put the logo in a `#header` that is outside (so, in your source just, just before) the `#content` div.

Comment: @Crashdown, that's where I originally had it but that puts it above the menu, whereas I really wanted it beside the menu. In reality it's nothing more than a cosmetic filler for an otherwise blank area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have the logo inside the 80% content you could position it absolutely. This will allow the logo to be positioned by the body, instead of `.content` (since `.content` is `position:static`).

Try out [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uvupo4/3/edit)

```
.content .logo { position: absolute; left: 48%; top: 10px; }
```

Comment: Thanks. It just needed a little tweaking but otherwise works fine. The logo is 250px wide, so the following works for me: .content .logo { position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -125px; top: 10px;}

Comment: @John Gardeniers - welcome! glad it worked out for you. I think the negative margin will be a good addition with a set width logo.